# Django models error, Now I want subtract from one charfiled other, but always equal to 0, like a default,. I'm beginner with working with django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

models.py -- there i create leave_links 10g field and want calculate him like substract by_projects_10g with on_facts_10g

```
class KT(models.Model):
  by_projects_10g = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  by_projects_100g = models.CharField(max_length=255)enter code here
  on_facts_10g = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  on_facts_100g = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  #now I want do like this, but an error comes out
  leave_links_10g = models.IntegerField(default=0)

  def calculate_leave_links(a,b):
    leave_links_10g = a -b 
    return leave_links_10g

  def query_links(self):
    calculate_leave_links(self.by_projects_10g, self.on_facts_10g)

#####views.py
def index(request):
  KT_links = KT.objects.all().values()
  template = loader.get_template('index.html')
  context = {
    'KT_links': KT_links,
  }
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to do db query on field leave_links_10g i sugest use @property:

```
@property
def leave_links_10g(self):
    try:
        return int(self.by_projects_10g) - int(elf.on_facts_10g)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

you can acces it like normal field e.g.:

```
kt_object.leave_links_10g
```

but if you want to do some db operations like filter or order_by you need to override save method of model KT:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        self.leave_links_10g =  int(self.by_projects_10g) - int(elf.on_facts_10g)
    except ValueError:
       self.leave_links_10g = 0
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Comment: Now I can't access to leave_links_10g django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'leave_links_10g' into field. Choices are: by_projects_100g, by_projects_10g, id, on_facts_100g, on_facts_10g

Comment: Show yours updated model and place where you get this error